# Set up NTFS security permissions to allow modify for subfolders/files but not parent

Tags: windows, permissions, ntfs, file-permissions, effective-permissions

I have the following directory structure:

CustomerName - SiteName - AssetName

The CustomerName/SiteName levels need to be view only of folder and contents. The AssetName folder name needs to be view only. I need users to be able to create/edit/delete files and subfolders within AssetName directory, and create/edit/delete any files and subfolders nested further down.

Is this possible - if so how?

Many thanks for all help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. CustomerName - for corresponding user or group: Security -> set only "Read & execute + List folder contents + Read"
2. AssetName - Security -> Advanced -> Change Permissions... -> Add -> same user or group -> set only "Create files / write data + Create folders / append data + Write attributes + Write extended attributes + Delete subfolders and files"

Check "Replace all child object permissions..."